# Java Download System Freezing

Tags: java, url, download, inputstream, outputstream

I've written an application that downloads a variety of files using the following basic algorithm:

```
InputStream reader = myURL.openStream();
OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
int bytesRead = 0;

while((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
{ 
    writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    buffer = new byte[153600];
}
```

This works well for most of my users, but a few have recently reported an issue where the download process starts but freezes part way in (one specific user reported that it always freezes ~10%-15% of the way through a ~30mb download). Oddly enough, no exception is thrown, which leads me to believe the condition of the while loop is what's causing the program to hang.

Am I right in my guess? Is there anything I can do about it?